# Adding and responding to reactions in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Code:

```py
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')



    async def on_message(self, message):
        words = [] # List of words to look for

        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        for i in words:
            if i in message.content.lower():
                await message.channel.send(f"Hey <@{message.author.id}>, i have noticed that in your message is a word on a list")
                break


            await message.add_reaction("✅")

            await client.wait_for("reaction_add")
            await message.delete()





client = MyClient()
client.run("TOKEN")
```

How Could i make the bot add reaction to its own message and if the user uses it delete its own message
i did look for the answer but god is discord.py messy, i have seen 6 answers that did not work and all of them seemed like they use different modules

i apologize if the answer was easy to find, but i just couldnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should always try to find your answer in the documentation ([`discord.py` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)). (Off-topic: it's not `discord.py` that's messy; it's likely the method you are using to find answers which is messy.)

The [`TextChannel.send()` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send) returns the message which was sent. So, you could just assign that return value to a variable.

For the other issue, there is an event listener which detects message deletions, [`on_message_delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_delete)

```py
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        ...

    async def on_message(self, message):
        words = []
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        for i in words:
            if i in message.content.lower():
                sent_message = await message.channel.send(
                    f"Hey {message.author.mention}, I have noticed that in your message is a word on a list"
                )
                break

            await sent_message.add_reaction("reaction")
            await message.add_reaction("✅")
            await client.wait_for("reaction_add")
            await message.delete()

    async def on_message_delete(self, message):
        # Do stuff here


client = MyClient()
client.run("TOKEN")
```

(On a side note, you can use [`Member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mention) to mention/ping a member, instead of `"<@{message.author.id}>"`.)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is preferable to use the `@client.event` method decorator above your event methods instead of putting them in their own class. You would declare the client object as `client=discord.Client()` at the top, then put `@client.event` above your event handling methods. The on_reaction_add method can have reaction and message parameters to respond.